# Create and save csv to storage in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv, save, storage

Found a handful of questions on here about this with no answer, so hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction...

I'm trying to create and save a csv file to storage, then update the DB in Laravel. I can create the file successfully, and I can update the DB successfully... but I'm stuck on putting them both together. In my controller, I have this for creating the file ([taken from here](https://codingdriver.com/export-csv-file-in-laravel-example.html)):

```
 public function updatePaymentConfirm(Request $request) {

   $users = User::all();
   $fileName = 'test.csv';

   $headers = array(
      "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
      "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
      "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
      "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
      "Expires"             => "0"
   );

   $columns = array('First Name', 'Email');

   $callback = function() use($users, $columns) {
      $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
      fputcsv($file, $columns);

      foreach ($users as $user) {
          $row['First Name']  = $user->first_name;
          $row['Email']    = $user->email;

          fputcsv($file, array($row['First Name'], $row['Email']));
      }

         fclose($file);
   };

   // return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
 }
```

When the function completes, the last line (that's commented out) prompts the user to download the newly created file (which is not the functionality I'm looking for). I tried adding this to my controller in its place for saving to storage and also updating the database:

```
   $fileModel = new UserDocument;

   if($callback) {
       $filePath = $callback->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');

       $fileModel->name = $fileName;
       $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
       $fileModel->save();

       return back()
       ->with('success','File has been uploaded.')
       ->with('file', $fileName);
    }
```

It saves a row to the db, albeit incorrectly, but it doesn't save the file to storage. I've reworked the `$filePath` line a million times, but I keep getting this error `Call to a member function storeAs() on resource` or something similar. I'm relatively new to working with Laravel, so I'm not sure what I should be looking for. Thoughts?

Comment: You're getting that error because you've defined `$callback` as a function that doesn't return anything, and then you're trying to call the `storeAs` method on it. [Saving uploaded files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files) and [returning files for download](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads) are two entirely opposite actions and would each have different controller methods with little or no code shared between them.

Comment: @miken32 - the second part is a piece I grabbed from a controller for uploading a file, so that makes sense. I'm not trying to return the file for download (or return the file at all to the user) - I'm trying to take the CSV that's created and store/save/put it in storage. It doesn't even need the if statement, but I'm honestly trying anything at this point.

Comment: Is the user uploading a file, or are you just creating it from data in the request?

Comment: I'm creating it from data in the request and data currently in the DB. The page/view itself is a confirmation page just confirming all the data we have for the user is correct. When they confirm/submit, that data needs to be compiled and written to a CSV and saved with some other files we have for the user.

Comment: Ok this is way too broad to answer effectively, but in short: 1 [make a temp file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php); 2 [write the CSV stuff to it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php); 3 [save the temp file to storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files); 4 write your info to the database.

Comment: Any help is better than no help! Thank you! :) I'll see what I can come up with from this.

Comment: After reading more on it, I didn't have to use `$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');` to create the file. Just calling for a file that doesn't exist creates the file (unless the file exists - then it updates it), so that solved for my saving issue. Updating the DB was just a matter of putting the file path that I created it in. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `php://output` is a virtual "file" that just goes to standard output. On command line that's the screen, and on a web server it's the client browser. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removed everything and started over... got it! And for anyone else running into the same issue: just calling for a file that doesn't exist creates the file (unless the file exists - then it updates it), so you don't have to create a temp file or use `$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');` to create the file. It'll automatically "save" the newly generated file in the file path you specified when you `fclose()` out of the file.

The only thing I'll note is that the ***file path has to exist*** (the file doesn't, but the file path ***does***). In my instance, the file path already exists, but if yours doesn't or if you're not sure if it does, check to see if it exists, and then [make the directory](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#directories).

```
public function updatePaymentConfirm(Request $request) {

    $user = Auth::user();

    $path = storage_path('app/public/docs/user_docs/'.$user->id);

    $fileName = $user->ein.'.csv';

    $file = fopen($path.$fileName, 'w');

    $columns = array('First Name', 'Email Address');

    fputcsv($file, $columns);

        $data = [
            'First Name' => $user->first_name,  
            'Email Address' => $user->email,    
        ];


    fputcsv($file, $data);

    fclose($file);

    $symlink = 'public/docs/user_docs/'.$user->id.'/';

    $fileModel = new UserDocument;
    $fileModel->name = 'csv';
    $fileModel->file_path = $symlink.$fileName;
    $fileModel->save();

    return redirect()->route('completed');

}
```

### ** **UPDATE** **

Everything worked perfectly locally, and when I pushed this to production, I received this error :

```
fopen(https://..../12-3456789.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections.
```

I'm saving to an s3 bucket, and I had to rework the entire process. You can't create and/or write to a file in the directory. I had to create a temp file first. Here's where I landed:

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $storage = Storage::disk('s3')->url('/');
    $path = 'public/docs/user_docs/'.$user->id.'/';

    $csvFile = tmpfile();
    $csvPath = stream_get_meta_data($csvFile)['uri'];

    $fd = fopen($csvPath, 'w');

    $columns = array('First Name', 'Email Address');
    $data = array(
            'First Name' => $user->first_name,  
            'Email Address' => $user->email,    
          );

    fputcsv($fd, $columns);
    fputcsv($fd, $data);

    fclose($fd);

    $s3->putFileAs('', $csvPath, $path.$user->ein.'.csv');
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I have fixed it with this snipe:

```
// output up to 5MB is kept in memory, if it becomes bigger it will
// automatically be written to a temporary file
$csv = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:'. (5*1024*1024), 'r+');

fputcsv($csv, array('blah','blah'));
rewind($csv);
$output = stream_get_contents($csv);

// Put the content directly in file into the disk
Storage::disk('myDisk')->put("report.csv", $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is easy and functional, use Laravel Storage Class
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#main-content

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// data array
$results = [
  ['id' => 0, 'name' => 'David', 'parent' => 1],
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Ron', 'parent' => 0],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mark', 'parent' => 1]
];

// create a variable to store data
$pages = "id,name,parent\n"; // use " not ' or \n not working

// use foreach to data
foreach ($results as $where) {
  $pages .= "{$where['id']},{$where['name']},{$where['parent']}\n";
}

// use Fecades Laravel Storage
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.csv', $pages);
```

Comment: That method won't work if your data has commas in it. The reason to use fputcsv would be that it handles the edge cases of the csv format.